# SessionFactory loads wrong config file in karaf

Tags: hibernate, osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

I'm trying to create 3 bundles:

- BundleA: use unmanaged-native hibernate to access database 1.
- BundleB: also use unmanaged-native hibernate but access database 2.
- BundleC: imports BundleA and BundleB.

I expect that bundleA and bundleB will get session factory with their config file.
However, Hibernate's log shows that **BundleB gets session factory using BundleA's config file**.

Does anyone can give me any advise?

---

BundleA's blueprint.xml:

```
<bean id="dao" class="idv.peayton.osgi.core.bundle1.Dao" init-method="init" />  
<bean id="serviceImpl" class="idv.peayton.osgi.core.bundle1.impl.B1ServiceImpl">
    <property name="dao" ref="dao" />
</bean>
<service id="service" ref="serviceImpl" interface="idv.peayton.osgi.core.bundle1.B1Service" />
```

BundleA's hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/se00001?autoReconnect=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <mapping resource="entity/b1.mapping.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

BundleB's blueprint.xml:

```
<bean id="dao" class="idv.peayton.osgi.core.bundle2.Dao" init-method="init" />  
<bean id="serviceImpl" class="idv.peayton.osgi.core.bundle2.impl.B2ServiceImpl">
    <property name="dao" ref="dao" />
</bean>
<service id="service" ref="serviceImpl" interface="idv.peayton.osgi.core.bundle2.B2Service" />
```

BundleB's hibernate.cfg.xml: (difference between BundleA is url and mapping resource)

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/m00001?autoReconnect=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <mapping resource="entity/b2.mapping.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

The Dao class looks like below:

```
public void init() {
    logger.info("Initializing session factory...");
    if (sf == null) {
        Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(Dao.class);
        logger.info("Using bundle: " + bundle);

        BundleContext context = bundle.getBundleContext();
        logger.info("Using context: " + context);

        ServiceReference sr = context.getServiceReference(SessionFactory.class.getName());
        logger.info("Using servRef: " + sr);

        sf = (SessionFactory) context.getService(sr);
        logger.info("SessionFactory is: " + sf);
    }
}
```

And the logs look like below:

```
2014-05-29 15:33:32,582 | INFO  | Local user karaf | HibernateUtil                    | 206 - peayton-blueprint-core-bundleA - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Initializing session factory...
2014-05-29 15:33:32,582 | INFO  | Local user karaf | HibernateUtil                    | 206 - peayton-blueprint-core-bundleA - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Using bundle: peayton-blueprint-core-bundleA [206]
2014-05-29 15:33:32,582 | INFO  | Local user karaf | HibernateUtil                    | 206 - peayton-blueprint-core-bundleA - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Using context: org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl@c6e491
2014-05-29 15:33:32,582 | INFO  | Local user karaf | HibernateUtil                    | 206 - peayton-blueprint-core-bundleA - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Using servRef: [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]
2014-05-29 15:33:32,598 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Configuration                    | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
2014-05-29 15:33:32,598 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Configuration                    | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
2014-05-29 15:33:33,707 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Configuration                    | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: entity/b1.mapping.xml
2014-05-29 15:33:35,176 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Configuration                    | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
2014-05-29 15:33:35,192 | WARN  | Local user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
2014-05-29 15:33:35,207 | INFO  | Local user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
2014-05-29 15:33:35,207 | INFO  | Local user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
2014-05-29 15:33:35,207 | INFO  | Local user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/se00001?autoReconnect=true]
2014-05-29 15:33:35,207 | INFO  | Local user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=username, password=****}
2014-05-29 15:33:35,379 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Dialect                          | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2014-05-29 15:33:35,426 | INFO  | Local user karaf | TransactionFactoryInitiator      | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2014-05-29 15:33:35,426 | INFO  | Local user karaf | ASTQueryTranslatorFactory        | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2014-05-29 15:33:35,598 | INFO  | Local user karaf | HibernateUtil                    | 206 - peayton-blueprint-core-bundleA - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | SessionFactory is: org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@1a85af4
2014-05-29 15:33:35,598 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Dao                              | 207 - peayton-blueprint-core-bundleB - 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT | Initializing session factory...
2014-05-29 15:33:35,598 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Dao                              | 207 - peayton-blueprint-core-bundleB - 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT | Using bundle: peayton-blueprint-core-bundleB [207]
2014-05-29 15:33:35,598 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Dao                              | 207 - peayton-blueprint-core-bundleB - 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT | Using context: org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl@866459
2014-05-29 15:33:35,598 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Dao                              | 207 - peayton-blueprint-core-bundleB - 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT | Using servRef: [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]
2014-05-29 15:33:35,629 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Configuration                    | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
2014-05-29 15:33:35,629 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Configuration                    | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
2014-05-29 15:33:35,863 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Configuration                    | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: entity/b1.mapping.xml
2014-05-29 15:33:37,348 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Configuration                    | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
2014-05-29 15:33:37,348 | WARN  | Local user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
2014-05-29 15:33:37,348 | INFO  | Local user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
2014-05-29 15:33:37,348 | INFO  | Local user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
2014-05-29 15:33:37,348 | INFO  | Local user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/se00001?autoReconnect=true]
2014-05-29 15:33:37,348 | INFO  | Local user karaf | verManagerConnectionProviderImpl | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=username, password=****}
2014-05-29 15:33:37,363 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Dialect                          | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2014-05-29 15:33:37,363 | INFO  | Local user karaf | TransactionFactoryInitiator      | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
2014-05-29 15:33:37,363 | INFO  | Local user karaf | ASTQueryTranslatorFactory        | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2014-05-29 15:33:37,363 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Dao                              | 207 - peayton-blueprint-core-bundleB - 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT | SessionFactory is: org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@88dcd7
```

---

**Edit:** Why I got this conclusion

In bundleA's hibernate.cfg.xml, I tried to read mapping file from **entity/b1.mapping.xml**.
In bundleB, I tried to read mapping file from **entity/b2.mapping.xml**.
But in the log, it looks like that hibernate read mapping file from **entity/b1.mapping.xml, in both bundle**.

Log of bundldA:

```
2014-05-29 15:33:33,707 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Configuration                    | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: entity/b1.mapping.xml
```

Log of bundleB:

```
2014-05-29 15:33:35,863 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Configuration                    | 110 - org.jboss.logging.jboss-logging - 3.1.0.GA | HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: entity/b1.mapping.xml
```

According to this [document](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch17.html#d5e4990), I get session factory in Dao class's init method by using SessionFactory service which was exported by hibernate-osgi service.
Before calling **getService** method, I print bundle name to check if I get the wrong bundle, but the bundle name is as my expect.

```
2014-05-29 15:33:32,582 | INFO  | Local user karaf | HibernateUtil                    | 206 - peayton-blueprint-core-bundleA - 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT | Using bundle: peayton-blueprint-core-bundleA [206]
```

and

```
2014-05-29 15:33:35,598 | INFO  | Local user karaf | Dao                              | 207 - peayton-blueprint-core-bundleB - 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT | Using bundle: peayton-blueprint-core-bundleB [207]
```

My environment is:

- Apache Karaf 3.0.1
- Hibernate 4.2.12.Final

p.s. HibernateUtil class was the Dao class, I changed its name while asking this question. Sorry if it makes any confusion. :(

Comment: Who is the bundle that export SessionFactory Service? It seems that you get the same service in both daos

Comment: I get org.hibernate.SessionFactory service from hibernate-osgi bundle. according to [hibernate's document](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch17.html#d5e4990)

Comment: Sorry, don't see from the logging that the wrong configuration file is taken. Maybe you can give some information where you get the conclusion from.

Comment: @ArievanWijngaarden , I edited the post adding the reason why I got the conclusion at the bottom. Thank you :)

Comment: I have a question, i am a newbie, but how  did you get the mysql driver to work?  what is verManagerConnectionProviderImp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into the code of hibernate-osgi, I concluded that this is a bug in the hibernate-osgi class `org.hibernate.osgi.OsgiSessionFactoryService`. You should file a bug there.

For a detailed explanation:
Method `getService` from `OsgiSessionFactoryService` provides your bundle the `SessionFactory` instance. However, for some reasons, this service adds all the bundles that request a session factory to the bundles that are subsequently searched for configuration files. See code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-osgi/4.3.3.Final/org/hibernate/osgi/OsgiSessionFactoryService.java?av=f) line 85. As a result, the second bundle requesting a session factory will always get the previous configuration.

Although I didn't check this, I think you can bypass this bug by putting your configuration file in a different path in only one of your bundles, for example in `/cfg/hibernate.cfg.xml` for bundle A. Since the path differs among the bundles, I assume it will be found by the correct loader.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @ArievanWijngaarden :) I have not thought that may be a bug... I'll try to look deeper into the source code to see if it is.

Comment: You should really try the different location bypass.

Comment: I just tried to place the cfg.xml files in different location and it looks like worked!(The log shows that hibernate reads the config file in the correct locations, although I have not tried to access the dao acturally...). Thanks a lot for your help!